# How to use AWS TransferManager to download multiple files from S3 as ZIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to download AWS directory as ZIP. Currently I'm using below Java code to download multiple files from directory.

```
public static void downloadDir(String bucket_name, String key_prefix,
      String dir_path, boolean pause)
{
    System.out.println("downloading to directory: " + dir_path +
          (pause ?  " (pause)" : ""));

    TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();

    try {
        MultipleFileDownload xfer = xfer_mgr.downloadDirectory(
                bucket_name, key_prefix, new File(dir_path));
        // loop with Transfer.isDone()
        XferMgrProgress.showTransferProgress(xfer);
        // or block with Transfer.waitForCompletion()
        XferMgrProgress.waitForCompletion(xfer);

    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    xfer_mgr.shutdownNow();
}
```

Is there a way to download the directory as ZIP?

Answer (score 0):

No way with the standard AWS SDK utilities.

You can either postprocess the downloaded folder to zip it programatically or change the format of your S3 files to be already zipped.